# mongoDB query to find the document in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
[{
  "username":"user1",
  "products":[
           {"productID":1,"itemCode":"CODE1"},
           {"productID":2,"itemCode":"CODE1"},
           {"productID":3,"itemCode":"CODE2"},
       ]
},
{
  "username":"user2",
  "products":[
           {"productID":1,"itemCode":"CODE1"},
           {"productID":2,"itemCode":"CODE2"},
       ]
}]
```

I want to find all the "productID" of "products"  for "user1" such that "itemCode" for the product is "CODE1".

What query in mongoDB should be written to do so?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: @ReubenL. thnx,

Comment: I'd do `$match` -> `$unwind` -> `$replaceRoot` -> `$match` -> `$project`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to match a single condition, then the dot notation is sufficient.
In Mongo shell:

```js
db.col.find({"products.itemCode" : "CODE1", "username" : "user1"})
```

This will return all users with nested product objects having itemCode "CODE1".

**Updated**

Wasn't clear on your requirements at first but this should be it.

If you want each product as a separate entry, then you would need to use the aggregate framework. First split the entries in the array using `$unwind`, then use `$match` for your conditions.

```js
db.col.aggregate(
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  { $match: { username: "user1", "products.itemCode": "CODE1" } }
);
```

response:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57cdf9c0f7f7ecd0f7ef81b6"), "username" : "user1", "products" : { "productID" : 1, "itemCode" : "CODE1" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57cdf9c0f7f7ecd0f7ef81b6"), "username" : "user1", "products" : { "productID" : 2, "itemCode" : "CODE1" } }
```

Comment: This will give me the products of user2 too, which i dont want.

Comment: Ah I missed that requirement, you can just add that as an additional param.

Comment: `db.col.find({"username": "user1", "products.itemCode" : "CODE1"})`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is

```
db.col.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$products" },
   { $match: { username: "user1", "products.itemCode": CODE1 } },
   { $project: { _id: 0, "products.productID": 1 } }
]);
```

In my case didn't work without [ ] tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple filter for this like below which is nothing but `AND` condition (assuming your collection name is `collection1`)

```
db.collection1.find({"username":"user1", "products.itemCode" : "CODE1"})
```

Comment: It will not work because finally it is going to return the whole data with "username" as "user1"

Comment: In that case you should use $unwind