# Query nested array from document

Tags: mongodb, bson

Given the following document data in collection called 'blah'...

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60913f55987438922d5f0db6"),
    "procedureCode" : "code1",
    "description" : "Description 1",
    "coding" : [
        {
            "system" : "ABC",
            "code" : "L111"
        },
        {
            "system" : "DEFG",
            "code" : "S222"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60913f55987438922d5f0dbc"),
    "procedureCode" : "code2",
    "description" : "Description 2",
    "coding" : [
        {
            "system" : "ABC",
            "code" : "L999"
        },
        {
            "system" : "DEFG",
            "code" : "X3333"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

What I want to get is all of the coding elements where `system` is `ABC` for all parents, and an array of `codes` like so.

```
[
{ "code": "L111" },
{ "code": "L999" },
]
```

If I use `db.getCollection('blah').find({"coding.system": "ABC"})` I get the parent document with any child in the `coding` array of `ICD`.

If I use...

```
db.getCollection("blah")
    .find({ "coding.system": "ABC" })
    .projection({ "coding.code": 1 })
```

I do get the parent documents which have a child with a system of "ABC", but the coding for "DEFG" seems to come along for the ride too.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60913f55987438922d5f0db6"),
    "coding" : [
        {
            "code" : "L989"
        },
        {
            "code" : "S102"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60913f55987438922d5f0dbc"),
    "coding" : [
        {
            "code" : "L989"
        },
        {
            "code" : "X382"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried experimenting with:

```
 db.getCollection("blah").aggregate(
   { $unwind: "$coding" },
   { $match: { "system": "ICD" } }
 );
```

.. as per this page: [mongoDB query to find the document in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338112/mongodb-query-to-find-the-document-in-nested-array)
... but go no where fast with that approach. i.e. no records at all.

What query do I need, please, to achieve something like this..?

```
[
{ "code": "L111" },
{ "code": "L999" },
...
]
```

or even better, this..?

```
[
"L111",
"L999",
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "coding.system": "ABC" }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$coding"
  },
  {
    $match: { "coding.system": "ABC" }
  },
  {
    $project: { code: "$coding.code" }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bm8fhrn6SAF)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "coding.system": "ABC" }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$coding"
  },
  {
    $match: { "coding.system": "ABC" }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      coding: { $push: "$coding.code" }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WsngPrbfXVr)

Comment: -Both work as a solution, thank you, but the second is perfect as it is just an array of values.

Now I need to work out how to make this distinct!

Comment: @Dib change `$push` into `$addToSet` can make this distinct

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$unwind`, `$match` you can also use `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "coding.system": "ABC" } },
  {
    $project: {
      coding: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$coding",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.system", "ABC" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Excellent thank you.
Does `$$this` take the scope of each object in the projection?

Comment: Yes, it is the default. You can define your own, if you prefer, for example `{$filter: { input: "$coding", as: "code",  cond: { $eq: [ "$$code.system", "ABC" ] }}}`